# operator wchar_t**() failing to provide implicit conversion to const wchar_t ** - why?

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I have a problem understanding why a certain implicit conversion is not working as I expect it. I have the following class

```
ref class ManagedWStringArrayWrapper
{
    wchar_t** m_pointer;

public:

    operator wchar_t**()
    {
        return m_pointer;
    }
};
```

and I thought this would implicitly convert to const wchar_t ** as well - but it doesn't. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: can you provide a sample how you use that operator?

Comment: There's an entry on the C++ FAQ about this: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.17

Comment: +1 That is interesting. For a single level of indirection (wchar_t *), the const wchar_t*() operator allows implicit conversion. It's only for multiple levels of indirection where it fails. Joys of C++.

Comment: That is because a const pointer to a pointer is not the same as a const pointer to a const pointer!

Comment: @adelphus: When you look at it in detail, and consider that it's the _pointee_ (and then the pointee's pointee) that you're trying to make `const`, it makes complete sense. OTOH, `T**` will convert to `T** const` just fine, as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conversion from `T**` to `T const**` is not as intuitive as you might expect — in fact, it's given as an example in the standard itself as `const`-incorrect code.

The example given is:

```
#include <cassert>  

int main() {  
  char* p = 0;  

  //char const** a = &p; // not allowed, but let's pretend it is  
  char const** a = (char const**)&p; // instead force the cast to compile  

  char const* orig = "original";  
  *a = orig; // type of *a is char const*, which is the type of orig, this is allowed  

  assert(p == orig); // oops! char* points to a char const*  
}
```

Study the above scenario for a while and it will become clear that this is *not* the same as a conversion `T*` → `T const*`. Not at all!

I asked the same question in [a blog post](http://kera.name/articles/2009/12/a-question-on-indirect-constness/), and the FAQ has [an entry on it](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.17) too.

Comment: Similarly, you can't implicitly convert `Derived**` to `Base**`. And for the same reason, because if you could then `Derived *pd, **ppd = &pd; Base **ppb = ppd; *ppb = new Base;` would result in `pd` containing a pointer to a `Base` object with no objection from the type system and no explicit casts to warn readers that something un-type-safe is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Because those are different things. If you look, for instance, at the C++ libraries, you'll find that there are often two functions for doing the same thing, one operating on const pointers and the other on non-const. [Example.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/)

But you can easily add an explicit operator `const wchar_t**`.

Comment: Read between the lines @Mr Lister - if you add the const wchar_t** operator (did you even bother to try?) it fails unless you explicitly cast the return value. The question is why?

Comment: Nope, not the same reason. If you add a conversion to `wchar_t*` it can convert to `wchar_t const*` implicitly.

Comment: Yes, I bothered to try. And it compiled. Want me to post my source?

Comment: @MrLister: [That is impossible](http://codepad.org/3ZOu6k5s). You must have misunderstood.

Comment: Apparently, I had a different idea of "cast the return value".

Comment: I thought it meant "cast the result of the function invoked" rather than "in the function, cast the member to the type of the return value before returning".